# Javascript GET request after POST request

Tags: javascript, http

I have a page that uses a function for getting some data, with a GET xhttp request, from a database (get_worktime_list()).
On the same page, I can add some data to the database with a form using a POST xhttp request and after a success (saved in the response) I will get the content included the new line from the database with the same function get_worktime_list().

The problem is that when getworktime is called after the POST request, get_worktime_list() makes another POST request instead of a GET. why???

```
function http_request(post_data, end_point, type)
{
    console.log("HTTP");
    var res = 0;
    //var data = "data=0&username="+stored_token.username+"&token="+stored_token.token;
    var data = "data=0&"+post_data;
    console.log(data);
    
    // Check if is valid token/username from database
    const url = "http://192.168.1.188:5000/services/"+end_point;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            res = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            
        }
    };

    if (type == "GET")
    {
        console.log(url+"?"+post_data);
        xhttp.open("GET", url+"?"+post_data, false);
    }
    else 
    {
        console.log("Data: "+data);
        xhttp.open("POST", url, false);
    }

    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhttp.send(data);
    xhttp.abort();

    return res;
}
```

This add data to DB

```
function addworktime(username,token)
{
    
    console.log("Aggiungo ore");
    var date = document.getElementById("data").value;
    var type = document.getElementById("turno").value;
    var pay = document.getElementById("paga").value;
    var emp = document.getElementById("dipendente").value;
    var ore = document.getElementById("num_ore").value;

    var data = "username="+username+"&token="+token+"&day="+date+"&turn_type="+type+"&pay="+pay+"&emp="+emp+"&ore="+ore;
    var res = http_request(data,"admin/dipendenti/addtime.php","");

    //console.log(res);
    if (res.insert_ok == 1)
    {  
        
        display_time_table(0,0,null);
        
    } else {
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

This function makes a GET request when a page load and a POST request when called by addworktime()

```
function display_time_table(from,to,cf)
{
    let time_list_table = document.getElementById("list-container");
    var time_list = get_worktime_list(saved_data.username,saved_data.token,from,to,cf);
    let time_table = generate_time_list_table(time_list);

    time_list_table.innerHTML = time_table;
}
```

```
function get_worktime_list(username,token,date_from,date_to,cf)
{
    
    var data = "username="+username+"&token="+token;

    if (cf != "" || cf != null)
    {
        data = data+ "&dipendente="+cf;
    }

    if (date_from != 0)
    {
        data = data +"&date_from="+date_from;
    }

    if (date_to != 0)
    {
        data = data + "&date_end="+date_to;
    }

    
    var time_list = http_request(data,"admin/dipendenti/getworktime.php", "GET");

    return time_list;
}
```

The server can only accept GET requests for that API and obviously, I get a parse error parsing the JSON response.

Thanks for help

Comment: This question is missing important information. It contains neither this `getworktime()` function, nor how it's being called.

Comment: Sorry getworktime() was a name for make the concept. i will add in the question the information requiered, however the function get_worktime_list(username,token,date_from,date_to,cf) is called for the first time (correctly) by the html page and then by the function addworktime() as explained in the post